# SQL Query to compare columns in different table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have TableA and TableB which contains identical columns but they have different records.

How do I find out which "UniqueID" is not in TableA but in TableB?

I have been doing

```
select tc.uniqueid, td.uniqueid
from tab1c as tc
left join tab2c as td
where tc.uniqueid != td.uniqueid;
```

but it doesnt seem to be correct.

Comment: you could use except

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left join:

```
select tc.uniqueid, td.uniqueid
from tab1c as tc
left join tab2c as td
on tc.uniqueid = td.uniqueid
where td.uniqueid = NULL; --Will get all uid in tab1c and not in tab2c
```

The same efficient and more readability way is `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select tc.uniqueid
from tab1c as tc
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tab2c as td
                  WHERE tc.uniqueid = td.uniqueid)
```

Answer (score 1):

The below query will find all the unique id`s which is not there in tableA

```
SELECT UNIQUEID FROM TABLEB WHERE  UNIQUEID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT UNIQUEID FROM TABLEA);
```

Comment: The `select distinct` is utterly and totally redundant.

Comment: Not in and in would be inefficient, if tables are large, using left join is better.

Comment: @Rajesh It's not; in SQLite, the implementation is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most efficient way but you can use [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188055.aspx)

```
    SELECT UNIQUEID
    FROM tab1c

    EXCEPT

    SELECT UNIQUEID
    FROM tab2c
```